# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pythonetl-xlrd (from python-etl) (from versions: none)

Tags: python, installation, pip, package, etl

Trying to install Python-ETL & getting below error:

pip install Python-ETL

Collecting Python-ETL

Using cached Python-ETL-1.01.zip (10.0 MB)

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pythonetl-xlrd (from python-etl) (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for pythonetl-xlrd

Answer (score 1):

`pythonetl-xlrd`, which seems to be a requirement for `Python-ETL` only has a python 2.7 wheel file available on pypi.

You are probably using python 3x (as python 2 has reached end of life a time ago).

If you really need this particular library, then you will need to use python 2.7 and install it there. Otherwise, I would advise you to just look for another ETL library that fits your need.

Comment: I thought so, seems like a silly question now